# Google Analytics Reporting Use Two Date Ranges

Tags: php, google-analytics

In v4 of the Google Analytics Reporting API for php, the documentation states support has been added for specifying two date ranges in one request:

> The request can have a maximum of 2 date ranges

However I am not seeing any examples of how to add two date ranges, without manually creating the entire request JSON (ie I am using the functional method outlined in Google's [quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php)). In the guide, a date range is made by:

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("STARTING_DATE");
$dateRange->setEndDate("ENDING_DATE");
```

In many functions, to add an additional value to be set, you simply create an array, so I attempted the following but it is invalid:

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate(array("START_ONE", "START_TWO"));
$dateRange->setEndDate(array("END_ONE", "END_TWO"));
```

As a last-ditch effort I tried to format the values as a JSON to comply with the JSON request object created, but that was still invalid:

```
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("{startDate: START_ONE, startDate: START_TWO}");
$dateRange->setEndDate("{endDate: END_ONE, endDate: END_TWO}");
```

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong or if using two date ranges is even possible through the use of the functions it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two date range objects as in the [multiple date ranges sample](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#multiple_date_ranges)

```
// Create DateRange objects.
$march = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$march->setStartDate("2015-03-01");
$march->setEndDate("2015-03-31");

$january = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$january->setStartDate("2015-01-01");
$january->setEndDate("2015-01-31");

...

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId("XXXX");
$request->setDateRanges(array($march, $january));
$request->setDimensions(array($browser));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
```

Note it is not intended to use multiple date ranges with the `ga:date`. To read the results you need to access the two fields in the response:

```
function printResults(&$reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```